# Bash for loops and hostnames and how to generate them

Tags: bash, hostname

Why doesn't this work?

```
NODE_ROOT=node0
INFRA_DOMAIN=example.com
for host in $NODE_ROOT{1..3}.$INFRA_DOMAIN; do echo $host; done
```

I'm expecting:

```
node01.example.com
node02.example.com
node03.example.com
```

However, I get:

```
.example.com
.example.com
.example.com
```

How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
$NODE_ROOT{1..3}.$INFRA_DOMAIN
```

by

```
${NODE_ROOT}{1..3}.$INFRA_DOMAIN
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue with your script is that Bash is not able to interpret `$NODE_ROOT{1..3}` correctly. To help, you need to enclose the variable in quotes, `"`, which is generally accepted as 'good practice' in any case. You can also use the `"${VARIABLE}"`-type syntax to help Bash out too.

For example,

```
NODE_ROOT=node0
INFRA_DOMAIN=example.com
for host in "$NODE_ROOT"{1..3}."$INFRA_DOMAIN"; do echo $host; done
```

or

```
for host in "${NODE_ROOT}"{1..3}."$INFRA_DOMAIN"; do echo $host; done
```

Further reading:

- Stack Overflow question *[When do we need curly braces in variables using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748831)*

Answer (score 0):

You can simply modify your script to read:

```
NODE_ROOT=node0
INFRA_DOMAIN=example.com
for n in {1..3}; do echo ${NODE_ROOT}${n}.${INFRA_DOMAIN}; done
```